# Lag in Ubuntu after updating firmware

Tags: 18.04, updates, firmware

I have intense lag my system while working with it, everything was Ok before updating firmware and Ubuntu.

I have no idea which one is related to the lag, firmware update or the OS.

[![System Monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6gsy.png)]

[[Click here for free-h & sysctl vm.swappiness & grep -i swap /etc/fstab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUhbd.png)]

Lag starts after a few minutes, everything is Ok here: 
[[System monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6gsy.png)]

[[htop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmROJ.png)]

[[top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84M3u.png)]

[[ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18TD7.png)]

[[ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BP2Lk.png)]

```
amir@amir:~$ sudo dmidecode -s bios-version
1.13.1
```

**UPDATED**

[[TOP & HTOP 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogbL3.png)]

[![TOP & HTOP 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HaJ0s.png)]

Comment: Which firmware... the BIOS? Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `grep -i swap /etc/fstab`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema Updated. thank you

Comment: Everything looks fine there, except there's a lot of CPU activity. Is the CPU/RAM overclocked? Which firmware did you update... the BIOS? What version Ubuntu did you update from/to? Once the system starts to lag again, show me `top` or `htop`. Also show me screenshot(s) of the `Disks` app SMART Data & Tests, SMART Data window.

Comment: Yes, when I turned on the system (dell XPS 15 9550) a warning message started displaying "Firmware update" or something like that... I use Ubuntu 18.04 which is the last update. I've updated the question, I couldn't use SMART Data & Tests it looks like disabled. @heynnema Thank you

Comment: Google Chrome and gnome-shell are eating up your CPU time. Do you have any gnome-shell extensions installed? Edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`. Is your Chrome up to date? How many open tabs?

Comment: You didn't answer the rest of my questions.

Comment: Also show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`.

Comment: @heynnema I just installed a theme on chrome. question updated. thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

One of your GNOME Shell extensions is causing your problem.

Plus, you have a number of added extensions, all by the same author, installed in the wrong place.

First, go to https://extensions.gnome.org/local/ and temporarily disable ALL extensions, and restart GNOME Shell (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type `r` then <kbd>↵</kbd>), or log out/in. Your problem should be gone. Then re-enable ONE extension at a time until your problem returns... and that's the bad one.

Second, all extensions in `/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`, except for the two *.ubuntu.com extensions, should be in `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`.

Google Chrome may also be a factor, if you have many tabs open, or have themed it with a defective theme.

Comment: Thanks for your time. nothing changed.

Comment: @TheMir After disabling the extensions, you restarted GNOME Shell, yes? It would be very instructive  to see if the GNOME Shell CPU usage came down from 26%, to something less than 3%, when nothing else is running. It would also be instructive to reboot, NOT start Chrome, but to use Firefox instead, and see if it's still laggy. Report back.

Comment: Yes I disabled all of them and rebooted. It's really looks strange right now I opened 7 tabs in chrome at a same time and Firefox is running and everything is stable and the important point is all of extensions are enabled but User Themes.

Comment: @TheMir Great news! Looks like you may have found it. If my answer was helpful, please remember to accept my answer by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Actually not, I still have that problem. IDK why. Thank you

Comment: You said "*I opened 7 tabs in chrome at a same time and Firefox is running and everything is stable*". Did I misunderstand? Please tell me more.

Comment: Yes I said, but It happens time to time. right now that I'm writing this comment everything look like fine.

Comment: right now 1 hour from my last comment when I plugged-in my charging cable it started being laggy.

Comment: I just checked using top command, Xorg uses almost 40 to 87% of CPU.

Comment: I restarted the system and suddenly my battery charge percentage came down from 60% to 8%.

Comment: Let's try and reset the power manager... unplug from AC, leave computer on, no sleep, until the battery is dead. Then hold down the POWER button for 15 seconds. Replug AC, let battery charge. Retest for lags.

Comment: Xorg will show higher usage if you've got some app running that's doing a lot of I/O to the screen. If it STAYS that high, then there's a problem.

Comment: I did, It’s still laggy after re-plugging AC. What did you mean by “pressing for 15 seconds”, nothing happened just BIOS setting came up.

Comment: @TheMir You didn't follow the instructions in my comment. Please re-read it. You drain the battery when no AC is connected. When the computer shuts down, hold down the POWER button for 15 seconds. Let go of the POWER button. Then reconnect the AC, charge the battery. Retest.

Comment: I did it as you said sir, but as I told you nothing happened. I drained battery then I press POWER button for 15 seconds. I charged the battery and tested it again, It's still laggy. I've updated the question and added two images captured during charging.

Comment: @TheMir Uninstall the SNAP version of Firefox and install the non-snap standard Firefox. Firefox is using way too much CPU.  Disable ALL of your GNOME Shell extensions again, as your gnome-shell is still taking too much CPU. It should be under 3% at idle. Make sure your video drivers are up to date.